# distcc on osx not distributing compilations

Tags: osx

I've just installed distcc with homebrew on a few osx machines, and added their ip addresses on /usr/local/Cellar/distcc/3.2rc1/etc/distcc/clients.allow, and ~/.distcc/hosts.

Then, I start a compilation with -j16, but watching distccmon-text shows me that all the compilation is being done on my machine only...

I exported DISTCC_LOG and DISTCC_VERBOSE, and in the log, I see a lot of these..

```
distcc[72899] (dcc_parse_hosts_file) load hosts from /Users/joao.pincho/.distcc/hosts
distcc[72899] (dcc_parse_hosts) found tcp token "192.168.6.10"
distcc[72899] (dcc_lock_host) got cpu lock on 192.168.6.10 slot 0 as fd6
distcc[72894] (dcc_parse_hosts) found tcp token "192.168.6.10"
distcc[72899] (dcc_lock_host) got cpu lock on localhost slot 0 as fd7
distcc[72899] (dcc_note_state) note state 3, file "(NULL)", host "localhost"
distcc[72895] (dcc_parse_hosts) found tcp token "192.168.6.10"
distcc[72894] (dcc_lock_host) /Users/joao.pincho/.distcc/lock/cpu_tcp_192.168.6.10_3632_0 is busy
distcc[72894] (dcc_lock_host) got cpu lock on 192.168.6.10 slot 1 as fd6
distcc[72894] (dcc_lock_host) /Users/joao.pincho/.distcc/lock/cpu_localhost_0 is busy
distcc[72895] (dcc_lock_host) /Users/joao.pincho/.distcc/lock/cpu_tcp_192.168.6.10_3632_0 is busy
distcc[72894] (dcc_lock_host) got cpu lock on localhost slot 1 as fd7
distcc[72894] (dcc_note_state) note state 3, file "(NULL)", host "localhost"
distcc[72895] (dcc_lock_host) /Users/joao.pincho/.distcc/lock/cpu_tcp_192.168.6.10_3632_1 is busy
distcc[72895] (dcc_lock_host) got cpu lock on 192.168.6.10 slot 2 as fd6
distcc[72895] (dcc_lock_host) /Users/joao.pincho/.distcc/lock/cpu_localhost_0 is busy
distcc[72895] (dcc_lock_host) /Users/joao.pincho/.distcc/lock/cpu_localhost_1 is busy
distcc[72895] (dcc_lock_host) got cpu lock on localhost slot 2 as fd7
```

The other iMac is idle, with a 8 distccd processes being run.
Why does it keep saying that the CPU is busy? What else do I need to do to distribute the compilation? Thanks.